# How to surround params in a string with quotes using Windows batch

Tags: windows, batch-processing

I have a Windows batch script which get's called by a Web-Tool which also passes CGI-Style parameters to the script, e.g. `?param=value1&param2=value2w&param3=multi%20word%20value&param4=104`

The batch should mangle the string to a set of commandline parameters, like: `-param1=value1 -param2=value2 -param3="multi word value" -param4=104`

The main challenge is to surround multi-word-params by quotes.